# Calendar getTime() only returns EST

Tags: java, calendar, timezone

```
Calendar cl =  Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
cl.setTimeInMillis(time); 
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), cl.getTime().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

What ever time I put it always returns the time in EST. I want it to return the time in PST. Does anyone know that could posibly be wrong?

P.S.
My local time is EST.

Comment: I think you found a bug.  See my comment to Grabriel's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST"));
Calendar cl = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Comment: Yeah, that works.  I'm calling "bug" on getting an instance with a TimeZone.  I tested it and I can get the values (dow, hour, sec, etc) manually and they are all correct for timezone passed into `getInstance`, but the expectation would be that `getTime` would do the same.  Just sayin`.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't really an answer but it's too big to put into a comment.  This is what I found.

My test looked like this

```
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
    Calendar cl = Calendar.getInstance(tz);

    System.out.println(tz.getDisplayName());
    String dayname = cl.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.SHORT,Locale.US);
    String monthname = cl.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH,Calendar.SHORT,Locale.US);
    int hour = cl.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    int min = cl.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int sec = cl.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    int mill = cl.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
    int year = cl.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    System.out.println("Time = " + cl.getTime().toString());
    System.out.println("Manually = " +
                           dayname + " " + monthname + " " +
                           hour + ":" + min +":" + sec + ":" + mill + " " +
                           cl.getTimeZone().getDisplayName(Locale.US) + " " + year);
```

Which gave the output

```
Pacific Standard Time
Time = Tue Nov 05 11:36:33 EST 2013
Manually = Tue Nov 8:36:33:238 Pacific Standard Time 2013
```

Looking at `Calendar.getTime()`:

```
public final Date getTime() {
    return new Date(getTimeInMillis());
}
```

Following the bouncing ball...

```
public long getTimeInMillis() {
    if (!isTimeSet) {
    updateTime();
    }
    return time;
}

private void updateTime() {
    computeTime();
    // The areFieldsSet and areAllFieldsSet values are no longer
    // controlled here (as of 1.5).
    isTimeSet = true;
}
```

But I don't have the source for `computTime()` so that's where I stopped.

Gabriel's answer works, fwiw.

Answer (score 1):

Calendar.getTime() returns a java [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) instance which represents the number of milliseconds from the epoch January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT. Calling toString() on a Date instance will print the date based on the timezone configured on the server. To properly format a date for output in another timezone, you'll want to look at using a date formatter.

```
TimeZone est = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(est);

DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
formatter.setTimeZone(est);
System.out.println(formatter.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Comment: The issue isn't with the format.  The issue is that he's specifying a timezone and `getTime` isn't honoring it.  `Calendar.getTime()` doesn't simply do `return new Date()`, btw.  It does `return new Date(getTimeInMillis());` and that `getTimeInMillis` does some hidden calculation -- which doesn't seem to work.